Javascript dropdown script won't execute on Wordpress page
I've been trying to create something simple to develop a dropdown menu for my Wordpress website so that you can click a piece of text and a dropdown menu with different links is shown (as you can see here). I followed W3 Schools guidance but I can't make it work on my website.
I tried adding the code to functions.php but my site crashed. When adding it to header.php the site worked correctly but the code didn't work, so I'm a bit lost here.
I'm no expert on Javascript at all and I can't seem to find the source of the problem, so your advice is much appreciated.
Here's the code I've used:
JAVASCRIPT:
//MENU DROPDOWN DESPLEGABLE AL CLICKAR ENLACES
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
add_action ('wp_head', 'myFunction');

HTML:
<div class="dropdown">
  <p onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</p>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

CSS:
/* Dropdown Button */
/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #5e7c6d;
  cursor: url(https://imthemoisturizer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Cursor-2.png), auto;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd; cursor: url(https://imthemoisturizer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Cursor-2.png), auto;}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}

Thanks in advance, have a nice day!

I am not sure if this will solve your problem but maybe you need to write function myFunction() {
return function(){document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show")};
}

 if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) { means the containing code only runs if the clicked element is NOT the dropdown button.

Thanks for your reply @mykaf! So how could I change the syntax to make it work correctly?

Thanks for your reply @Mehdi! I tried the change you stated. Now the website won't crash when adding the code to functions.php but the code doesn't work yet, so there must be something else I'm not seeing.

How exactly do you think if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) { works? Seems like you need to reverse the boolean so that it works when you click the dropdown.


I tried adding the code to functions.php but my site crashed.

Because the code you have written is Javascript and functions.php is a PHP file, which is evaluated as PHP. Now, Javascript is not valid PHP code, hence the crash that you experienced.

When adding it to header.php the site worked correctly

Because you either copied your Javascript code into the HTML and then it was shown as if it was plain text, or you added it to a <script> tag where it belongs, but it was not perfect yet. See my snippet below is working if I comment out the last JS line:


//MENU DROPDOWN DESPLEGABLE AL CLICKAR ENLACES
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  let myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  if (myDropdown) {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  }
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}

//add_action ('wp_head', 'myFunction');
/* Dropdown Button */
/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #5e7c6d;
  cursor: url(https://imthemoisturizer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Cursor-2.png), auto;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd; cursor: url(https://imthemoisturizer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Cursor-2.png), auto;}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
<div class="dropdown">
  <p onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</p>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>



Which means that as long as your HTML ends up being into the page source, if the Javascript from above is loaded into your page, then it will work. You can create a myfile.js file where you put in your Javascript and load this file via a script tag, like
<script src="path/to/myfile.js"></script>

